# Laravel : How to retrieve information from another table using a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-8, laravel-blade

the problem is that I have forms and I want to get all the members of it.

I have created a ***table pivot groupes*** which retrieves form_id from the ***table forms*** and user_id from the ***table users***.
but when I try to retrieve the information I get this :
Attempt to read property "firstname" on bool (View: /.../resources/views/groupes/list.blade.php)

In my Models I have :
Forms :

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function groupe()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Groupe::class);
    }
```

User:

```
public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Forms::class);
    }

public function groupe()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Groupe::class);
    }
```

list.blade.php ($forms correspond to 1 single form I had made a foreach before of all my forms):

```
@foreach($forms->user as $user)
  {{$user->firstname}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$forms->user` is neither a collection nor an array. it is a user instance got from belongsTo relation in Form model. that's why the error occurs

Comment: as mentioned that is a model instance you are trying to iterate, not a collection of models ... when you iterate an object like that you get its public properties

Answer (score 1):

`Groupe` is your pivot table, which contain user_id and form_id. As the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) described, if the pivot table is not joining the two related model names in alphabetical order (should be `form_user` in this case), then you need to include the table name, which is `groupe`:

```
public function groupe(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Groupe::class, 'groupe');
}
```

And if you want to get `User` of a `form`, then:

```
public function getFormWithUser()
{
    $form = Form::with('groupe')->first();
}
```

*note: But I'm a little confused with `form` relation in `User` model and vice versa, if this relation is `Many to Many` (since there's `groupe` pivot model), how could they related to each other directly ?